# Ignore optparse if value is given

Tags: python

I would like to have the ability to pass an argument w/o having to specify an option for optparse.  If I do pass an option, it has to be a known option or else the script will fail.

Rsync the following file to destination

```
myscript.py filename
```

Rsync the following folder to destination (all this is figured out in function I create).

```
myscript.py -f foldername
```

The reason is, I have an array (or dict) that ties with the "foldername." If no options are passed, the argument given in the CLI is a file that's in the working folder where the user calls the script.  Passing `-f` means to upload a folder whose value is stored in a dict (user can be in any directory, this folder's path is known ahead of time).

Am I better off adding options for both options? `-f` for file and `-v` for folder aka version?

Comment: Another approach you can probably follow is, check the argument and then process it accordingly. For example, if os.path.isdir(argument): // handle directory. if os.path.isfile(argument): handle file. Maybe this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am always a fan of being explicit, but you can short circuit optparse.

```
# args[0] is always the executable's name
if len(args) > 1:
    parser.parse_args(args, options)
else:
    #open file
```

Comment: If args = sys.argv, remember that len(args) is always >= 1.  This is because argv[0] is the name of the script.

Comment: ha, thanks, I had that at first but changed it for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Treat `-f` as an option with no argument and use it to switch the behavior of the positional argument (i.e. `foldername`).

Answer (score 0):

`parser.parse_args()` always returns two values:

- *options*, an object containing values for all of your options
- *args*, the list of positional arguments leftover after parsing options

([Totorial](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html#tutorial))

As such, you could do something like this:

```
parser = OptionParser()
parser.add_option("-f", "", action="store_true", dest="folder", default=False)
(options, args) = parser.parse_args(sys.argv)

fname = args[1] # name of folder or file

if options.folder:
    # do stuff for folder
else:
    # do stuff for file
```